# Pin configuration for DAC (AD767KNZ)

Tags: dac

I want the DAC(AD767KNZ) to output a signal 0V to 5V.

What should I connect to VCC and VEE?

DATASHEET :
http://docs-europe.electrocomponents.com/webdocs/10b5/0900766b810b5166.pdf

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See note 6 on the datasheet, You need a minimum of +11.4 V on Vcc, and -11.4 V on Vee for the 5V range.

The maximum is +15V Vcc and -15V Vee.

That gives you a fairly large range to aim for, so no great accuracy is needed from regulators.